# How to manually predict data from Machine Learning model

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I finally managed to come up with a really good ML model, with an accuracy over 90%. Great! But now I need to use this in real world :)

My dataset is something like this: every time a user accessed my website in the last 2 years I saved in a database if that user was using a computer or a smartphone, time of the day, week day, where the user is located.. And every time in the future, if the user did a conversion on my website, I would update the database to save that this particular user made a conversion.

I trained my ML algorithm using `Naive Bayes` (I used `[Rubix ML][1]` library for PHP which is pretty great, the devs behind it are awesome and kind people) and the results were surprisingly good, it can 90% of the time predict if a user that accessed my website will convert. That's a huge milestone to me!

So now comes the real world part: I need to extract some "logic" from the model. I can save the model weighs/configs to a `txt` file after training it, and then I can load that configurations and start making predictions on the fly.

BUT I CANT make predictions on the fly on my use case, here is the why: I am using Google Ads to advertise this website and I need to tell Google Ads "*hey google, please show my ads only to people using computer, at night, on saturday which are female ate 18-24 age*". I need to tell that to Google before running my campaign.

So here comes the real world part: how do I make any sense of those weights/configs saved in the `txt` file? **I would like to know the relationship/interaction that the ML model found on my columns (device, gender, age, location...) and tell google only to run my campaign in the best favorable conditions**, I mean, only when I am pretty confident a conversion will be made. I can run my prediction algorithm on Google Ads and tell google every time I participate in an auction "*hey google, according to my predictions, this person, using this device, at this time of the day... does not worth my bidding, so please dont show my ads to this person*".

THERE IS CLEARLY a relationship between the columns/features (device, gender, age...) because if I analyze the features isolated there is no evident pattern that `computer` is worth more showing ads than `smartphone`, same is true to age, gender... There is no clear winner, sure I can see some pretty small fluctuations that some features are better than others, but mostly, it's not clear at all. So I am pretty sure the features are highly dependent on each other.

Do you have any idea on how I can extract some logic from the `txt` file in order to know which columsn/features are worth more?

I dont know if it will be of any help, but I am providing you my `txt` file, just so you can see what I am dealing with.

```
O:31:"Rubix\ML\Classifiers\NaiveBayes":6:{s:8:" * alpha";d:1;s:12:" * logPriors";a:2:{s:3:"sim";d:-1.8178620931306924;s:4:"não";d:-0.1771818088907544;}s:12:" * fitPriors";b:1;s:10:" * weights";a:2:{s:3:"sim";i:604;s:4:"não";i:3120;}s:9:" * counts";a:2:{s:3:"sim";a:68:{i:0;a:2:{i:1;i:241;i:0;i:363;}i:1;a:2:{i:1;i:108;i:0;i:496;}i:2;a:2:{i:0;i:366;i:1;i:238;}i:3;a:2:{i:1;i:359;i:0;i:245;}i:4;a:2:{i:1;i:71;i:0;i:533;}i:5;a:2:{i:0;i:567;i:1;i:37;}i:6;a:2:{i:0;i:241;i:1;i:363;}i:7;a:2:{i:0;i:567;i:1;i:37;}i:8;a:2:{i:0;i:578;i:1;i:26;}i:9;a:2:{i:0;i:581;i:1;i:23;}i:10;a:2:{i:0;i:346;i:1;i:258;}i:11;a:2:{i:0;i:523;i:1;i:81;}i:12;a:2:{i:0;i:442;i:1;i:162;}i:13;a:2:{i:0;i:482;i:1;i:122;}i:14;a:2:{i:0;i:591;i:1;i:13;}i:15;a:2:{i:1;i:24;i:0;i:580;}i:16;a:2:{i:0;i:566;i:1;i:38;}i:17;a:2:{i:0;i:567;i:1;i:37;}i:18;a:2:{i:0;i:564;i:1;i:40;}i:19;a:2:{i:0;i:579;i:1;i:25;}i:20;a:2:{i:0;i:517;i:1;i:87;}i:21;a:2:{i:0;i:596;i:1;i:8;}i:22;a:2:{i:0;i:569;i:1;i:35;}i:23;a:2:{i:0;i:560;i:1;i:44;}i:24;a:2:{i:0;i:563;i:1;i:41;}i:25;a:2:{i:0;i:592;i:1;i:12;}i:26;a:2:{i:0;i:567;i:1;i:37;}i:27;a:2:{i:0;i:561;i:1;i:43;}i:28;a:2:{i:0;i:576;i:1;i:28;}i:29;a:2:{i:0;i:561;i:1;i:43;}i:30;a:2:{i:0;i:575;i:1;i:29;}i:31;a:2:{i:0;i:562;i:1;i:42;}i:32;a:2:{i:0;i:593;i:1;i:11;}i:33;a:2:{i:0;i:599;i:1;i:5;}i:34;a:2:{i:0;i:499;i:1;i:105;}i:35;a:2:{i:0;i:593;i:1;i:11;}i:36;a:2:{i:0;i:555;i:1;i:49;}i:37;a:2:{i:0;i:577;i:1;i:27;}i:38;a:2:{i:0;i:492;i:1;i:112;}i:39;a:2:{i:0;i:506;i:1;i:98;}i:40;a:2:{i:0;i:549;i:1;i:55;}i:41;a:2:{i:0;i:599;i:1;i:5;}i:42;a:2:{i:0;i:564;i:1;i:40;}i:43;a:2:{i:1;i:108;i:0;i:496;}i:44;a:2:{i:0;i:599;i:1;i:5;}i:45;a:2:{i:0;i:472;i:1;i:132;}i:46;a:2:{i:0;i:601;i:1;i:3;}i:47;a:2:{i:0;i:591;i:1;i:13;}i:48;a:2:{i:0;i:580;i:1;i:24;}i:49;a:2:{i:0;i:602;i:1;i:2;}i:50;a:2:{i:0;i:595;i:1;i:9;}i:51;a:2:{i:0;i:600;i:1;i:4;}i:52;a:2:{i:0;i:602;i:1;i:2;}i:53;a:2:{i:0;i:600;i:1;i:4;}i:54;a:2:{i:0;i:596;i:1;i:8;}i:55;a:2:{i:0;i:598;i:1;i:6;}i:56;a:2:{i:0;i:598;i:1;i:6;}i:57;a:2:{i:0;i:602;i:1;i:2;}i:58;a:2:{i:0;i:602;i:1;i:2;}i:59;a:2:{i:0;i:603;i:1;i:1;}i:60;a:2:{i:0;i:599;i:1;i:5;}i:61;a:2:{i:0;i:601;i:1;i:3;}i:62;a:2:{i:0;i:596;i:1;i:8;}i:63;a:2:{i:0;i:602;i:1;i:2;}i:64;a:2:{i:0;i:601;i:1;i:3;}i:65;a:2:{i:0;i:602;i:1;i:2;}i:66;a:1:{i:0;i:604;}i:67;a:1:{i:0;i:604;}}s:4:"não";a:68:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;i:2059;i:1;i:1061;}i:1;a:2:{i:0;i:2600;i:1;i:520;}i:2;a:1:{i:1;i:3120;}i:3;a:1:{i:1;i:3120;}i:4;a:1:{i:1;i:3120;}i:5;a:2:{i:1;i:212;i:0;i:2908;}i:6;a:2:{i:1;i:2059;i:0;i:1061;}i:7;a:2:{i:0;i:2921;i:1;i:199;}i:8;a:2:{i:0;i:2981;i:1;i:139;}i:9;a:2:{i:0;i:2980;i:1;i:140;}i:10;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:11;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:12;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:13;a:2:{i:0;i:2591;i:1;i:529;}i:14;a:2:{i:0;i:3084;i:1;i:36;}i:15;a:2:{i:0;i:3010;i:1;i:110;}i:16;a:2:{i:0;i:2895;i:1;i:225;}i:17;a:2:{i:0;i:2966;i:1;i:154;}i:18;a:2:{i:0;i:2956;i:1;i:164;}i:19;a:2:{i:0;i:2923;i:1;i:197;}i:20;a:2:{i:0;i:2675;i:1;i:445;}i:21;a:2:{i:0;i:3087;i:1;i:33;}i:22;a:2:{i:0;i:2930;i:1;i:190;}i:23;a:2:{i:0;i:2912;i:1;i:208;}i:24;a:2:{i:0;i:2889;i:1;i:231;}i:25;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:26;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:27;a:2:{i:0;i:2944;i:1;i:176;}i:28;a:2:{i:0;i:2876;i:1;i:244;}i:29;a:2:{i:0;i:2972;i:1;i:148;}i:30;a:2:{i:0;i:2958;i:1;i:162;}i:31;a:2:{i:0;i:2823;i:1;i:297;}i:32;a:2:{i:0;i:3039;i:1;i:81;}i:33;a:2:{i:0;i:3068;i:1;i:52;}i:34;a:2:{i:0;i:2586;i:1;i:534;}i:35;a:2:{i:0;i:3078;i:1;i:42;}i:36;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:37;a:2:{i:0;i:2952;i:1;i:168;}i:38;a:2:{i:1;i:551;i:0;i:2569;}i:39;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:40;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:41;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:42;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:43;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:44;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:45;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:46;a:2:{i:0;i:3104;i:1;i:16;}i:47;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:48;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:49;a:2:{i:0;i:3099;i:1;i:21;}i:50;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:51;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:52;a:2:{i:0;i:3104;i:1;i:16;}i:53;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:54;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:55;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:56;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:57;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:58;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:59;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:60;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:61;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:62;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:63;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:64;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:65;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:66;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}i:67;a:1:{i:0;i:3120;}}}s:8:" * probs";a:2:{s:3:"sim";a:68:{i:0;a:2:{i:1;d:-0.917942259912628;i:0;d:-0.5097261184325736;}i:1;a:2:{i:1;d:-1.7155321038401707;i:0;d:-0.19828995997268575;}i:2;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.5015181380147443;i:1;d:-0.9304164341378038;}i:3;a:2:{i:1;d:-0.5207759546191588;i:0;d:-0.9015484501369516;}i:4;a:2:{i:1;d:-2.1302138670532593;i:0;d:-0.1264841471091196;}i:5;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06475856734816308;i:1;d:-2.7692938263429285;}i:6;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.917942259912628;i:1;d:-0.5097261184325736;}i:7;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06475856734816308;i:1;d:-2.7692938263429285;}i:8;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.04557750849631925;i:1;d:-3.1110431200649855;}i:9;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.040409538337876666;i:1;d:-3.228826155721369;}i:10;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.5575552061224552;i:1;d:-0.8500519243697767;}i:11;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.14538830174827225;i:1;d:-2.0001607388050613;}i:12;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.3133102160241788;i:1;d:-1.313129785262552;}i:13;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.22686333241674173;i:1;d:-1.594695630696897;}i:14;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.023373351185308713;i:1;d:-3.767822656454056;}i:15;a:2:{i:1;d:-3.1880041612011136;i:0;d:-0.042129229217403225;}i:16;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06652068234156232;i:1;d:-2.743318339939668;}i:17;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06475856734816308;i:1;d:-2.7692938263429285;}i:18;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.0700542549228735;i:1;d:-2.6933079193650067;}i:19;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.0438518825288494;i:1;d:-3.1487834480478325;}i:20;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.15690474380983138;i:1;d:-1.929543171591108;}i:21;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.014962872676712377;i:1;d:-4.209655408733095;}i:22;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06124362524071867;i:1;d:-2.8233610476132043;}i:23;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.07715908054661809;i:1;d:-2.6002174962989946;}i:24;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.0718257345712555;i:1;d:-2.6692103677859462;}i:25;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.02168558707158898;i:1;d:-3.841930628607778;}i:26;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06475856734816308;i:1;d:-2.7692938263429285;}i:27;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.07537813617562336;i:1;d:-2.622690352151053;}i:28;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.04903771956121486;i:1;d:-3.0395841560828405;}i:29;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.07537813617562336;i:1;d:-2.622690352151053;}i:30;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.05077232537342326;i:1;d:-3.005682604407159;}i:31;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.07360035792962409;i:1;d:-2.6456798703757523;}i:32;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.020000666706669543;i:1;d:-3.9219733362813143;}i:33;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.009950330853168092;i:1;d:-4.61512051684126;}i:34;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.19227188764712272;i:1;d:-1.7434408919572473;}i:35;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.020000666706669543;i:1;d:-3.9219733362813143;}i:36;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.08611169181873207;i:1;d:-2.4948569806411682;}i:37;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.047306117396936985;i:1;d:-3.0746754758941104;}i:38;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.20637081202662433;i:1;d:-1.6794921673569738;}i:39;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.17836898247813132;i:1;d:-1.8117601359347244;}i:40;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.09696170784279785;i:1;d:-2.3815282953341654;}i:41;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.009950330853168092;i:1;d:-4.61512051684126;}i:42;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.0700542549228735;i:1;d:-2.6933079193650067;}i:43;a:2:{i:1;d:-1.7155321038401707;i:0;d:-0.19828995997268575;}i:44;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.009950330853168092;i:1;d:-4.61512051684126;}i:45;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.24778459757738155;i:1;d:-1.5165308578475607;}i:46;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.006622540760493382;i:1;d:-5.020585624949423;}i:47;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.023373351185308713;i:1;d:-3.767822656454056;}i:48;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.042129229217403225;i:1;d:-3.1880041612011136;}i:49;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.004962789342129014;i:1;d:-5.308267697401205;}i:50;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.01663931900396467;i:1;d:-4.104294893075269;}i:51;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.008285051534106917;i:1;d:-4.797442073635215;}i:52;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.004962789342129014;i:1;d:-5.308267697401205;}i:53;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.008285051534106917;i:1;d:-4.797442073635215;}i:54;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.014962872676712377;i:1;d:-4.209655408733095;}i:55;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.011618387953865076;i:1;d:-4.460969837014002;}i:56;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.011618387953865076;i:1;d:-4.460969837014002;}i:57;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.004962789342129014;i:1;d:-5.308267697401205;}i:58;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.004962789342129014;i:1;d:-5.308267697401205;}i:59;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.003305788134499544;i:1;d:-5.713732805509369;}i:60;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.009950330853168092;i:1;d:-4.61512051684126;}i:61;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.006622540760493382;i:1;d:-5.020585624949423;}i:62;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.014962872676712377;i:1;d:-4.209655408733095;}i:63;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.004962789342129014;i:1;d:-5.308267697401205;}i:64;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.006622540760493382;i:1;d:-5.020585624949423;}i:65;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.004962789342129014;i:1;d:-5.308267697401205;}i:66;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:67;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}}s:4:"não";a:68:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.41576783929175054;i:1;d:-1.0783198992734933;}i:1;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.1825778356267258;i:1;d:-1.7904790593220103;}i:2;a:1:{i:1;d:0;}i:3;a:1:{i:1;d:0;}i:4;a:1:{i:1;d:0;}i:5;a:2:{i:1;d:-2.6849369353659522;i:0;d:-0.07066444258017576;}i:6;a:2:{i:1;d:-0.41576783929175054;i:0;d:-1.0783198992734933;}i:7;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.0662055087647326;i:1;d:-2.7479117345273405;}i:8;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.045879605750693664;i:1;d:-3.104586678466073;}i:9;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.04621500739730597;i:1;d:-3.0974692106972093;}i:10;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:11;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:12;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:13;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.18604404360321208;i:1;d:-1.7733520945292098;}i:14;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.011922164735889139;i:1;d:-4.435311188431153;}i:15;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.03620157259364352;i:1;d:-3.3366988997630433;}i:16;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.07514334756977041;i:1;d:-2.6256941018030915;}i:17;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.05092248078455562;i:1;d:-3.002803984156131;}i:18;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.05429858122290015;i:1;d:-2.940283627174797;}i:19;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06552128020570824;i:1;d:-2.757962070380842;}i:20;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.15415067982725836;i:1;d:-1.9459101490553135;}i:21;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.0109501899307106;i:1;d:-4.519868576459216;}i:22;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06313016036448493;i:1;d:-2.7939556730287474;}i:23;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.06929034411594272;i:1;d:-2.7038948491105663;}i:24;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.07721731996889954;i:1;d:-2.5994917294090674;}i:25;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:26;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:27;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.058365004989690265;i:1;d:-2.8700793685015484;}i:28;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.08172573752382947;i:1;d:-2.5449708905306503;}i:29;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.048902278077279634;i:1;d:-3.042282795129918;}i:30;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.05362244867516768;i:1;d:-2.952478900268615;}i:31;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.10031950246224468;i:1;d:-2.3491356145699727;}i:32;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.026616306675110037;i:1;d:-3.6395098538111244;}i:33;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.0171220464556412;i:1;d:-4.075937187523255;}i:34;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.18797491888934822;i:1;d:-1.763962354179371;}i:35;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.013868953150876944;i:1;d:-4.285028985381815;}i:36;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:37;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.05565221933145465;i:1;d:-2.9163303861523038;}i:38;a:2:{i:1;d:-1.732681054798282;i:0;d:-0.19456792318611196;}i:39;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:40;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:41;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:42;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:43;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:44;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:45;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:46;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.005460106707798186;i:1;d:-5.2130157570191615;}i:47;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:48;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:49;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.007071710602139796;i:1;d:-4.955186647717062;}i:50;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:51;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:52;a:2:{i:0;d:-0.005460106707798186;i:1;d:-5.2130157570191615;}i:53;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:54;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:55;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:56;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:57;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:58;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:59;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:60;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:61;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:62;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:63;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:64;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:65;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:66;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}i:67;a:1:{i:0;d:0;}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, when a user logs into your site, with his/her details, and you want to show ***your*** specific ads (eventually not showing any). According to your server technology, you develop a web component that displays your contents according to your predictions. These contents (pictures/text) would be linked to the actual marketing page, including your site as referer. Then you would be rewarded if clicked.

Maybe you want to show specific Google Ads, ones that you favor. That is Google Ads' job to select ads, I doubt if Google allows your choice. Google has its own prediction algorithms based on the (same) user's actions while browsing on Chrome.